# Why doesn't an answer show in top answers on my network profile?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-exchange, network-profile

It is not a big deal, but on Stack Overflow I answered a question that got a few upvotes: [StringBuilder exception on changing Capacity!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619182/stringbuilder-exception-on-changing-capacity/6619205#6619205)

Even though this is the second answer with the most up-votes I've posted, it doesn't show on my [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/fee081b1-1877-45f0-913e-0ecbee530b70?tab=top). Is that a bug, or am I missing something?

Related question:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97355/how-is-my-top-answers-list-on-stack-exchange-profile-created

Comment: Er, it does, as do all your other ≥5-score answers.

Comment: @Gilles It does now. Someone upvoted the answer after I posted this question and that must've caused it to start showing up there. I swear it wasn't there before... =]

Comment: How long has it had ≥5 upvotes? I think the list of questions is buffered; if it acquired the fifth upvote less than a few hours ago, that would explain it.

Comment: I posted that answer on July 8th, and it got almost all of its upvotes on that day or the day after, IIRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the answer on your network profile now.

In theory, "top questions" & "top answers" are only cached for a few minutes, so it's not totally clear what happened here. In any case, we'll keep on eye on these sorts of errors to see if they happen again.