# Stack Exchange profile page doesn't show all my top questions

Tags: support, stack-exchange, information-display, network-profile, top-questions

StackExchange profile page has an option of showing the top posts(ie, with score of 5+).

In [my profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/394477/nazik), it doesn't show all my top questions.

This [meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188163/can-we-have-a-notification-when-the-answer-to-any-of-my-question-got-edited) is missing.

What's the reason for that?

I've also tested it by logging out, but does the same.

I thought it may be [caching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100558/186599), so I waited for 2 days. The question is not there.

Comment: Closed questions don't show up on the top questions of your Stack Exchange profile.

Comment: On the contrary, it seems as though **answers** to closed questions show up.. my top answer belonged to a question that was closed as a duplicate, and it is displayed. [See here](http://stackexchange.com/users/3171311/joshc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't see some more questions with score of 5 and above in my SE profile.

- [Blank space occur in the reputation summary in profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191006/blank-space-occur-in-the-reputation-summary-in-profile-page)
- [Some of the users' profile picture are not appearing fully](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176257/some-of-the-users-profile-picture-are-not-appearing-fully)
- [Stack Exchange profile shows zero count before posting any posts on the respective site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197260/stack-exchange-profile-shows-zero-count-before-posting-any-posts-on-the-respecti)
- [Why is Raghav Sood's accounts count showing zero in his profile-page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198553/why-is-raghav-soods-accounts-count-showing-zero-in-his-profile-page)

All of them are closed questions.

But, I can see the [answer to the closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185743/186599) in the [top answers](https://stackexchange.com/users/394477/nazik?tab=top) list.

So, it is clear that the closed questions won't be appear in the top questions list in StackExchange profile, but the answers to those questions will be listed if they have the score of 5 or above.

Thanks for the info @Antony, @JoshC