# My most voted question isn't listed on my profile on "Top Questions". Why is that so?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, top-questions

On the site [security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) I asked [a question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/139738/company-can-tell-if-new-and-old-passwords-are-too-similar-is-there-a-security-p) which got 13 upvotes. Although that is my "best" question (in terms of upvotes), this question isn't listed on my [Stack Exchange profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/6128998/toogley). I'd expect it be the first one listed right below "Top Questions".

Why is that the case?

Comment: I guess because it's closed

Comment: [Closed questions don't show up.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198843/274942)